# Error with a User Defined Function

Tags: r, function, if-statement

I have a user defined function that I am using on the following data set:

```
Pos      
A
B
C
A
C
B
```

I created the following function to add a variable to the data set.

```
Predict <- function(Uncontested.REB.per.game, STL.per.game, BLK.per.game, Opp.FGA.at.rim.per.game, PTS.per.game, Passes.per.game, log.Points.created.by.assist.per.game, sqrt.Drives.Per.Game, Pos){
if (Pos=="A"){
Pred = 1}
  else if(Pos=="B"){
Pred=4}
else if(Pos=="C"){
Pred=5
}
}
```

When I use the following command(s):
    Data <- transform(Data, Pred = Predict(Pos)

I get the error "the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used". I think that it has something to do with using an "if" statement on that I want to apply to each row instead of just one element, so I also tried a variation of the code above:

```
Predict <- function(Pos){
if (Pos=="B" && Pos!="A"){
Pred = 1}
  else if(Pos=="A"&&Pos!="B"){
Pred=4}
else if(Pos=="C" && Pos!="A"){
Pred=5
 }
 }
```

However, this just put the same value for Pred in all of the rows despite the different positions.

Answer (score 1):

You should vectorize your function. For example change you conditions statements using `ifelse` :

```
Predict <- function(Pos){   
   Pred <- ifelse(Pos=="A",1,ifelse(Pos=="B",4,5))
   Pred
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! The function that I ultimately want to write is more complicated and will involve other variables, can I just replace the 1, 4 and 5 with this formula in the code above?

Comment: @Megan which formula?

Comment: It would be something along the lines of Pred =  (97*Height + 0.342 + .34*Weight + 17*Y), but the coefficients will change based on Pos